# How to calculate 100 meters south of a location in Objective C?

Tags: objective-c, ios7, latitude-longitude

I have the latitude and longitude of a location. Is there a way I could compute 100 meters south of that point?

I am writing code in Objective C for iOS7 platform.

I am looking for some functions that does the trick effectively.

I tried Haversine formula (given below). But calculation is becoming complex and the value isn't accurate as Haversine considers Earth a sphere.

```
a = sin²((φ1-φ2)/2) + cos(φ1)*cos(φ2)*sin²((λ1-λ2)/2)
c = 2*atan2(√a, √(1−a))
distance = R*c
(φ is latitude, λ is longitude, R is Earth’s = 6,371km)
```

Comment: On a scale of 100 metres, the fact that the Earth is not a sphere will have almost no impact.  Certainly the error will be vastly smaller than the accuracy of the GPS receiver in the phone.

Comment: I have to calculate thousands of such calculations in my program. The combined error was big and needed to be removed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out a way to do this. Thought of sharing the same...

1. Convert coordinates into `MKMapPoint` using `MKMapPointForCoordinate`.
2. Then add or subtract to x or y coordinates of the `MKMapPoin`t got in step 1. Use `MKMapPointMake` to perform this.
3. Convert `MKMapPoint` back to `CLLocationCoordinate2D`. Use `MKCoordinateForMapPoint` to perform this.

Answer (score 2):

The longitude represents location east/west, so it will remain unchanged.

Represent the latitude as a signed number of degrees, with positive numbers for north of the equator and negative numbers south of the equator. Then to go 100 meters south you want to go the number of degrees south corresponding to 100 meters. The circumference of the earth is 40075 km, or 40075000 m, and that represents 360 degrees. So 100 meters corresponds to 100/40075000*360, or  approximately 0.0008983 degrees. So subtract 0.0008983 degrees from the latitude to get your answer.

The above assumes that the earth is spherical. In fact it is an ellipsoid, and if you want to take that properly into account the answer will be more complicated, but for most purposes the calculation assuming a sphere should be good enough.